# How is Ricci flow related to computer graphics?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, computer-science, applied-mathematics, ricci-flow

I recently came across the book [Ricci Flow for Shape Analysis and Surface Registration: Theories, Algorithms and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461487803) by Wei Zeng and Xianfeng David Gu. Because, I just saw the book on the passing and then read a bit about it in Amazon, I still don't exactly know how Ricci flow is related to computer graphics and especially to 3D modelling in computer science. If someone can give me a comprehensive answer or point me to one, I would be glad.

On the other hand, I also would like to learn whether the Poincaré conjecture has some applications in computer graphics and 3D modelling.

Lastly, I want to learn what are some mathematical research topics in these areas that have (or may have) direct applications in computer graphics and 3D modelling.

Comment: Have you looked at David Gu's web page: http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~gu/

Comment: If you Google this topic, you can find many good articles. For example: "http://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.0401.pdf", "https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~wangy/paper/iccv07-ricci.pdf" and "http://cg.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/papers/yyl/GeneralRicci.pdf".

Comment: @ShahroozJanbaz: you need to edit out the closing quotes " out of the URL…

Comment: @Teyssier: it seems we just have one chance in MO to edit our comment!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps this—and its references both past & future
(["cited by 152" subsequent papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=17099166687551548421&as_sdt=40000005&sciodt=0,22&hl=en))—will help...?

> Jin, Miao, Junho Kim, Feng Luo, and Xianfeng Gu. "Discrete surface Ricci flow." *IEEE Transactions on Visualization and Computer Graphics*, no. **5** (2008): 1030-1043.
> (DOI).

[image: Fig12]

---

[David (Xianfeng) Gu](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/%7Egu/)'s work
was cited by [Deane Yang](https://mathoverflow.net/users/613/deane-yang)
in the comments.

Here is one among the (many) later papers, coauthored by David Gu:

> Wang, Yalin, Jie Shi, Xiaotian Yin, Xianfeng Gu, Tony F. Chan, Shing-Tung Yau, Arthur W. Toga, and Paul M. Thompson. "Brain surface conformal parameterization with the Ricci flow."
> *IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging.* **31**, no. 2 (2012): 251-264.
> ([Journal link](https://asu.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/brain-surface-conformal-parameterization-with-the-ricci-flow-2).)